# Java Switch statement with increment operator

Tags: java, switch-statement, increment

```
int k=0;

switch (k++) {
   case 0: System.out.println("0 is "+k);
}
```

Output:

> 0 is 1

Why 1? It's still in switch operator and must be incremented after exit from it.

Comment: The increment takes *immediately*. As in `0` is returned, `k` is incremented, then the program continues. Rough approximation and not perfectly correct, but that's the general idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Postfix means it will be incremented after evaluation, NOT after the current block.  In this case it's evaluated, increments k, then branches to the evaluation.  Exactly as it should.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing the switch statement does is process the expression `(k++)`. The result returned is compared to the case value(s). But since `k++` has already been processed, `k` has the value of `1`. Since it is a postfix operator, the value returned is the value before it was incremented. Thus `0` is returned, though the value after the expression is executed is `1`.